# nth-of-type CSS selector hierarchy issues

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want the background color of a div to alternative. Red, black, red, black... It works fine when the elements are in the same hierarchy level, but I can't get it working in this case:

```
<div class="post-preview-wrapper">
    <div class="post-preview">
         <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="post-preview-wrapper">
    <div class="post-preview">
         <h1>Adipisicing elit. A cumque!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.post-preview:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: red;
}

.post-preview:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Any hints how to set up the selector properly? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/L6nwC/

You might want to run the nth-child on the container...

```
.post-preview-wrapper:nth-of-type(even) .post-preview{
    background-color: red;
}

.post-preview-wrapper:nth-of-type(odd) .post-preview {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[nth-of-type](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/)**

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U9W2M/)**</kbd>

```
.post-preview-wrapper:nth-of-type(even) .post-preview{
    background-color: red;
}

.post-preview-wrapper:nth-of-type(odd) .post-preview{
    background-color: black;
}
```

**[nth-child](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)** also works

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U9W2M/1/)**</kbd>

```
.post-preview-wrapper:nth-child(2n) .post-preview{ /* even*/
    background-color: red;
}

.post-preview-wrapper:nth-child(2n+1) .post-preview{ /* odd */
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works fine. I accepted the first answer suggestion this solution.

Answer (score 0):

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QxHun/)

```
.post-preview-wrapper:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: red;
}

.post-preview-wrapper:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately applying the background to the parent doesn't work in my case.